# How to approach a Buffer Overflow problem with a limited string scanf and hashing?

Tags: c, scanf, sha1, buffer-overflow

PRE: There is only one similar question to this here with a different hashing algorithm and changed array sizes but that did not answer some questions in my head and post is from 2016. The problem is to perform a Buffer Overflow attack on a program which gets input as password, hashes it (SHA1) and compares the correct hash to it. (Scanf is limited)

Things I know already:

-NUL Byte (\x00) is accepted by scanf.

-If I feed 20 characters to input, the null terminator overwrites first correct hash value.

-If I feed with 37 characters input(scanf limit), then we overwrite the first 17 bytes in correct hash with our own and 18th with the null terminator.

I tried to write a python brute force script to find such a hash that it matches the last 3 bytes, but what I don't understand is, 18th byte from 20 bytes is null terminator in our correct hash. How to compare it? I tried doing like this but didn't work = "00a450" as the last 3 byte representation in string. Below is the code for C program and my python script.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <openssl/sha.h>

int
main(void) {
    FILE *file;
    unsigned char flag[128];
    unsigned char correct_hash[20] = {
        0x4a, 0xc9, 0xb0, 0x57, 0xf8, 0x02, 0x12, 0x60, 0x6c, 0xea,
        0xab, 0xf3, 0xc6, 0x50, 0x5d, 0xaf, 0xed, 0x40, 0xa4, 0x50
    };
    unsigned char password[20];

    printf("Insert your password: ");
    scanf("%37s", password);
    SHA1(password, strlen((char *)password), password);
    if(memcmp(password, correct_hash, 20) == 0) {
        printf("CORRECT PASSWORD!\n");
        file = fopen("/flag", "r");
        if(file != NULL) {
            fscanf(file, "%s", flag);
            fclose(file);
            printf("Flag: %s\n", flag);
        } else {
            printf("Error while opening the flag file\n");
        }
    } else {
        printf("WRONG PASSWORD!\n");
    }
    fflush(stdout);

    return 0;
}
```

```py
import hashlib
from itertools import *

st = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"
hash_ending = "00a450"
found = False
for i in range(2,3):
    perms = list(map("".join, permutations(st,i)))
    for permutation in perms:
       full_hash =  hashlib.sha1(permutation.encode()).hexdigest()
       print("Testing = " + full_hash)
       if(full_hash[-6:] == hash_ending):
           found = True
           print("Full Hash = " + full_hash )
           print("Password = " + permutation)
           break
    if(found == True):
        break
```

I have hard time understanding the NUL Byte and the overridden byte as string terminator in correct hash and its value when comparing.

Comment: Have you seen `memcmp`?

Comment: Yes but what it is useful for in this case? It still compares the 20 bytes from password and correct_hash.

Comment: It compares from wherever you tell it to start, for whatever length you give it.

Comment: So it's intentional, then, that `password` is only 20 chars long, but the `scanf` format with which it is being read *explicitly* accepts up to 37 bytes (plus a terminator)?  You are deliberately engineering a flawed program, I guess to explore how it can be attacked?

Comment: @JohnBollinger well it is a CTF assignment. So the purpose it to get the flag. I just do not understand how does the null terminator represented as and in hash.

Comment: @stark you mean by "wherever" as parameters (password, correct_hash) or index?

Comment: @Aegean, you have a misunderstanding.  A byte with value `0` does not have inherent significance as a string terminator.  That is a *role* it plays in situations where an array in which it resides is being treated as a string.  In any other situation, it's just a byte with value 0, much like an `int` with value 0.  That's why `scanf` happily reads it (external input is not an array being treated as a string) and why it has no special significance to `memcmp()` (which does not interpret the data it compares as strings).

Comment: So its gonna be skipped over in memcmp? Then if i overwrite correct hash and the last 3 bytes will be \x00\xa4\x50. So \x00 does not have any significance there? So during memcmp will it be skipped over to xa4?

Comment: 0 is a value, a4 is a value.  Nothing is skipped.  Use memcmp and memcpy for binary data. Use strcmp and strcpy for strings, where 00 has meaning.

Comment: The question is unclear. BTW: the python script does **not** find a usable password (you need longer permutations). And: you should use a generator instead of an in-memory list(), which would get too large.

Comment: @wildplasser The question is I can't get the string which should give the last 3 byte 0x00 0xa4 0x50 and how can I get it? I am not really good with brute force scripting.

Comment: You dont need to put them there, they are already there. Just put your (5char) password there + (40-2-5) NULs, and you are there.

Comment: @wildplasser did I understand what you mean wrong? I used this but it failed. echo -ne "\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00" | ./overshade